# Golang switch between structs

Tags: struct, go, interface, switch-statement

I'm new to golang and I'm trying to create a function that, based on the struct it's used on, will return a formatted string using Sprintf

```
type Name struct {
    Title string
    First string
    Last  string
}

type Location struct {
    Street string
    City   string
    State  string
    Zip    string
}

func Merge(m interface{}) string {
    switch m.(type) {
    case *Location:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s \n %s, %s %s", m.(*Location).Street, m.(*Location).City, m.(*Location).State, m.(*Location).Zip)
    case *Name:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s. %s %s", m.(*Name).Title, m.(*Name).First, m.(*Name).Last)
    }
    return "Not Applicable"
}

fmt.Println(Merge(Location))
```

I'm getting the "`Not Applicable`" message from my `PrintLn`. In one version of the code, I believe the message was "`out of index`".

Comment: You're not passing a `*Location` to `Merge`; that's why you're getting "Not Applicable".  Also, you may want to consider just implementing [`fmt.Stringer`](https://godoc.org/fmt#Stringer) for your types.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Tim. Can you expand on how I would use fmt.Stringer? The println(merge())) line was a simplification of what I have. The actual line I have is fmt.Println(Merge(servicesA.Users[0].Location))

Comment: What is the type of `servicesA.Users[0].Location`: `Location` or `*Location`? Also you might find useful `%v` or `%+v` with `Sprintf`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, kostya. It's supposed to be just Location. When I tried removing the pointer in the function (*Location to Location) and ran it, I got this: panic: interface conversion: interface is main.Location not *main.Location

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example you are trying to pass the struct itself to the function rather than an instance of the struct. When I ran your code it wouldn't compile. I agree with the comments above though, this would be much better handled by making sure each struct satisfies the fmt.Stringer interface.

[fmt.Stringer interface](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)

A fixed version of your code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Name struct {
    Title string
    First string
    Last  string
}

type Location struct {
    Street string
    City   string
    State  string
    Zip    string
}

func Merge(m interface{}) string {
    switch m.(type) {
    case Location:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s \n %s, %s %s", m.(Location).Street, m.(Location).City, m.(Location).State, m.(Location).Zip)
    case Name:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s. %s %s", m.(Name).Title, m.(Name).First, m.(Name).Last)
    }
    return "Not Applicable"
}

func main() {
    l := Location{
        Street: "122 Broadway",
        City: "New York",
        State: "NY",
        Zip: "1000",
    }
    fmt.Println(Merge(l))
}
```

A version using fmt.String:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Name struct {
    Title string
    First string
    Last  string
}

func (n *Name) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s. %s %s", n.Title, n.First, n.Last)
}

type Location struct {
    Street string
    City   string
    State  string
    Zip    string
}

func (l *Location) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s \n %s, %s %s", l.Street, l.City, l.State, l.Zip)
}

func main() {
    l := &Location{
        Street: "120 Broadway",
        City:   "New York",
        State:  "NY",
        Zip:    "1000",
    }
    fmt.Println(l)

    n := &Name{
        Title: "Mr",
        First: "Billy",
        Last:  "Bob",
    }
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom! That's a great explanation! When I typed out my Println function, I also forgot to include an & reference to the *Location in my Merge function. My final Println method came to this: fmt.Println(Merge(&servicesA.Users[0].Location)) After that change and reviewing your code, it worked the way I intended. Thanks again, Tom.

Comment: If you're going to use a type switch you shouldn't use type assertions in the case bodies. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/Wh9mAr4xzi.

Comment: The OP mentioned the example was a simplification, if you have multiple types that all want to have a common behaviour it's common to use an interface (`fmt.Stringer` would only be appropriate if that's a string representation of the whole type). E.g. perhaps something like https://play.golang.org/p/xq3a0RcbFa